# onNext start another Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

Is there any cleaner way to do the following?

I have a Android observable that debounces the requests. onNext it calls a second observable.

```
{// when creating the android activity
searchTextEmitterSubject = PublishSubject.create();
subscription = AndroidObservable.bindActivity(this, Observable.switchOnNext(searchTextEmitterSubject))
                .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        Log.d("a",s);
                        pa.doSearch(s);
                    }
                });
}

@OnTextChanged(R.id.ed)
public void onTextEntered(CharSequence charsEntered) {
    searchTextEmitterSubject.onNext(getASearchObservableFor(charsEntered.toString()));
}


private Observable<String> getASearchObservableFor(final String searchText) {
    return Observable.create( (Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) ->
            subscriber.onNext(searchText)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

doSearch instantiates a second observable:

```
public void doSearch(String string) {
    AlbumEndpoint albumEndpoint = API.getRestAdapter().create(AlbumEndpoint.class);
    Observable<Point> observable = albumEndpoint.searchPoint(string);
    mAdapterDataSubscription = AndroidObservable.bindActivity((Activity) getContext(), observable)
            .subscribe(mAdapterDataObserver);

}

private Observer<Point> mAdapterDataObserver = new Observer<Point>() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        mAdapterDataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Point point) {
        List<Point.Result> results = point.getResults();
        mData.addAll(results);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

};
```

It works. But is there a way to "merge" the two streams into one either improving readability or to create a most optimal code?

---

**Edit**: For sake of completeness and anyone interested in the future I manage to shrink the code into:

```
Observable<EditText> searchTextObservable = ViewObservable.text(ed);
searchTextObservable.debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap(editText -> {
            String string = editText.getText().toString();
            AlbumEndpoint albumEndpoint = getRestAdapter().create(AlbumEndpoint.class);
            return albumEndpoint.searchPoint(string);
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(mAdapterDataObserver);
```

Comment: **Wisdom**: You've provided an example with error in Retrofit usage: api service, created by the `RestAdapter` and the adapter itself **must be a Singletone**, as [Jake says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20627010/2938966). So creating a new instance on every debounce is a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

I am not sure, why you are wrapping the text change events into a new Observable every time instead of just handing them to your Subject right away:

So, instead of:

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.ed)
public void onTextEntered(CharSequence charsEntered) {
    searchTextEmitterSubject.onNext(getASearchObservableFor(charsEntered.toString()));
}
```

try this:

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.ed)
public void onTextEntered(CharSequence charsEntered) {
    searchTextSubject.onNext(charsEntered.toString());
}
```

Of course, then you would have a `PublishSubject<String>` instead of `PublishSubject<Observable<String>>`.

But you could skip the `onNextSwitch` and just `debounce` your Subject and continue from there.

To further simplify things, you could just use the ViewObservables from the rxjava Android package. I haven't used them lately but it should work like this:

```
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> searchTextObservable = ViewObservable.text(tvSearch);
```

A `OnTextChangeEvent` will then be emitted every time the underlying TextWatcher's `afterTextChanged` is called (in ButterKnife, by default, `onTextChanged` is used, so that may be a subtle difference).

In case I missed some important reason for wrapping each text change in an Observable, this can also achieved in a simpler way:

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.ed)
public void onTextEntered(CharSequence charsEntered) {
    searchTextEmitterSubject.onNext(
        Observable.just(charsEntered.toString())
    );
}
```

Note that I also omitted the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` - I have never felt the need to move event listeners from the UI thread to some other thread. Am I missing something here?

Finally, you could just use `flatMap` to actually execute the search for each search term (I am using my own `Observable<OnTextChangeEvent>` here):

```
searchTextObservable
.debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.flatMap(new Func1<OnTextChangeEvent, Observable<Point>>() {

    @Override
    public Observable<Point> call(OnTextChangeEvent event) {
        final String string = event.text.toString();
        AlbumEndpoint albumEndpoint = API.getRestAdapter().create(AlbumEndpoint.class);
        Observable<Point> pointObservable = albumEndpoint.searchPoint(string);
        return AndroidObservable.bindActivity((Activity) getContext(), pointObservable);
    }

})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(mAdapterDataObserver);
```

You may need to move your pointObservable to the IO thread if the albumEndpoint doesn't do so already.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to explain what `OnTextChangeEvent` is. That's a part of rx-android - you can have a look at the source code here:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/0.x/src/main/java/rx/android/events/OnTextChangeEvent.java

It is just a simple POJO that holds a reference to the EditText that was changed as well as the current content *of* the EditText. The latter is what I was using in the `flatMap`.

Comment: David, your answer is really helpful. Thanks. I still have some trouble understanding `OnTextChangeEvent` which since `tvSearch` is a `<T extends TextView>` that means in our case `OnTextChangeEvent` is probably an extended EditText. So what I did (didn't work): http://pastebin.com/cdgdJY6k [edit: just realized `searchTextSubject` is not bounded to the `searchTextObservable`, I'm trying more]

Comment: Thanks David. We were doing *almost* the same thing.