# Should @Provides annotated method for Retrofit class be annotated with @Singleton

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-2, dagger

I have a Dagger2 `@Module` class with the `@Provides` annotated method which calls `Retrofit.create` method:

```
@Provides
RestService provideRestService(final Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(RestService.class);
}
```

Should I annotate this method with the `@Singleton` annotation?

I see one reason to do it: **calling `create` each time has some cost** and one reason for not doing it: **keeping one instance has some cost** (Dagger performs double checking each time instance is requested).

Which solution is preferred? With or without `@Singleton` annotation? Or maybe it is not important at all? Or my approach to create this class in provider is fundamentally wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a good chance of performing some performance tests and share the results with the community, don't you think?

Comment: @Pelocho Yes, it is a good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If additional instances are allowed but potentially-expensive, you might also consider the use of [`@Reusable`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Reusable.html). You lose double-checked locking, but you (potentially) shorten object lifespans and gain flexibility about where the instances are installed.

> `@Reusable` is useful when you want to limit the number of provisions of a type, but there is no specific lifetime over which there must be only one instance.

See [the User's Guide topic](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#reusable-scope) or the SO question [Dagger @Reusable scope vs @Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39136042/1426891).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. You avoid memory allocation. Android will keep you the same instance untill the app is killed. Think about if you call the api like into a for loop and each time you create a new instance (not recommended and won't happen when you use dagger in same injectionm but just like an example). It will kill your memory. So you should use `@Singleton`.

Singleton will ensure you that you will use the same instance across module.