# Why Dagger's Reusable scope is Slower than Singleton?

Tags: performance, kotlin, dagger-2

I've always thought that, when working with Dagger2, we should use `@Reusable` scope instead of `@Singleton` if we don't need the guarantee to get always the same instance, since `@Singleton` used double checking, which is expensive and slow...

However, I've made a simple performance tests and here are the results:

```
Reusable  4474 ms
Singleton 3603 ms
```

Here is the code:

```
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {

    fun getReusable(): ReusableFoo

    fun getSingleton(): SingletonFoo
}

@Reusable
class ReusableFoo @Inject constructor()

@Singleton
class SingletonFoo @Inject constructor()

class TestClass {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
        measure {
            component.getReusable()
        }
        measure {
            component.getSingleton()
        }
    }

    private fun measure(block: () -> Unit) {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        (0..1000000000).forEach { block() }
        println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
    }
}
```

The same phenomenon when constructing heavier class (I've tried with `Retrofit`) and with `@Provide` annotated methods instead of constructor injection.

Did I make a mistake in my test or simply `@Reusable` is slower? If so, where should we use it? Does it have any benefits over `@Singleton`?

Comment: It is actually not that easy to construct a scenario where the DCL idiom is significantly more expensive than plain, non-threadsafe lazy init idiom. The only difference is that with DCL you always have to fetch from "memory", but in a tight loop you're just reaching to the CPU cache. Outside a tight loop, both idioms will probably need memory access and are on the same footing.

Comment: Another point: you have measured 3.6 nanoseconds for singleton and 4.4 nanoseconds for reusable. That's a difference of 0.8 nanoseconds, i bet there are lots and lots of candidate micro-level explanations for it, all of them quite unenlightening. Your real conclusion should be "it makes no difference at all" which scope you use. Or you should come up with a different benchmark that would show a more pronounced difference.

Comment: Try flipping the order of what you test first and I'd not be surprised if it suddenly stated the opposite, also possibly see here about micro benchmarks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/1837367

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I've tried it ;) But there was no difference. Thanks for this link - the response is very valuable, especially one comment below it: *Also, never use System.currentTimeMillis() unless you are OK with + or - 15 ms accuracy*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak) mentioned and linked in the comments, [micro benchmarks in the JVM are difficult to get right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/1837367). Even taking your results at face value, the calls average out to within 1ns and 20% of each other in a tight billion-call inner loop.

Though I've written a [separate SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39136042/1426891) with more details, I can address your question of "does it have any benefits":

1. The main *performance* advantage to `@Reusable` is *during construction in a multi-threaded app*, because in the event of a race condition `@Reusable` will *potentially* create a separate object for a separate thread rather than synchronizing the creation. Once you've paid the creation cost (as you do in the first call on each block), the next billion calls are free (or close to free), especially with JVM inlining and caching, and within the same stack in the same thread. Though your benchmark doesn't reveal it, you might still see better performance with `@Reusable` if there is any thread contention for your binding's creation.
2. The main *memory* advantage to `@Reusable` is that the reusable instance is kept in the narrowest component that uses it directly. If you have an Android Fragment component as your only consumer of a `@Reusable` binding, Android will release and reclaim that memory when you destroy the Fragment and collect its Component.
3. The main *Dagger usability* advantage to `@Reusable` is that, unlike `@Singleton` and custom scopes, `@Reusable` bindings can be included in any component regardless of how many scope annotations are on the component. If you have a `@Singleton` binding you are absolutely required to install the binding in a component annotated with `@Singleton`.
4. The main *developer usability* advantage to `@Reusable` is that, unlike bindings annotated with `@Singleton` or `@ActivityScoped`, you are declaring that the binding is *not stateful or otherwise required to be `@Singleton`*. If you want to use your binding outside of Dagger (or you want to replace Dagger someday), you'll need to document or determine whether a `@Singleton` binding is necessarily `@Singleton` or whether it's simply an optimization opportunity. With `@Reusable` that ambiguity disappears.